# SQL Server 2008 R2: Pivot table on VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDetails
(
    ID int,
    EmpName varchar(20),
    ColumnName varchar(20),
    ColumnValue varchar(20)
);
```

**Records**:

```
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(1,'S','Company','Microsoft');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(1,'S','Profession','Database');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(1,'S','Location','USA');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(1,'S','Company','Unisys');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(1,'S','Company','TATA');

INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(2,'U','Company','Microsoft');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(2,'U','Profession','Software');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(2,'U','Location','UK');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(2,'U','Company','DXC');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(2,'U','Company','AOL');

INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(3,'R','Company','Microsoft');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(3,'R','Profession','Software');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(3,'R','Location','UK');
INSERT INTO EMPDetails Values(3,'R','Company','AOL');
```

**My try**

**Condition 1** : `Company = 'Microsoft' AND Profession = 'Database'`

Expected Result:

```
ID  EmpName Company     Profession  Location
-----------------------------------------
1   S       Microsoft   Database    USA
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, EmpName,ColumnValue, ColumnName
  FROM EMPDetails
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ColumnValue) /*OR MIN()*/
  FOR ColumnName in ([Company], [Profession], [Location])
) piv
WHERE Company = 'Microsoft' AND Profession = 'Database'
```

**Condition 2** :  `Company = 'Microsoft' AND Profession = 'Software'`

Expected Result:

```
ID  EmpName Company     Profession  Location
-----------------------------------------
3   R       Microsoft   Software    UK
2   U       Microsoft   Software    UK
```

Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, EmpName,ColumnValue, ColumnName
  FROM EMPDetails
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ColumnValue) /*OR MIN()*/
  FOR ColumnName in ([Company], [Profession], [Location])
) piv
WHERE Company = 'Microsoft' AND Profession = 'Software'
```

**Question**: If I use `MIN()` aggregate function with condition 1, then will get result but not with `MAX()` and it's reverse for condition 2. Why?

Comment: What is the expected result for each of the two cases?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, Edited with expected result.

Comment: your condition for #2 actually works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d568/6

Comment: Will you always be returning the same columns *(`id`, `EmpName`, `Company`, `Profession`, `Location`)*?  Will you always only ever be searchign those columns?  Or might you want to search other `ColumnName` values, but not necessarily include them in your results?  If you searched for just `Profession = 'database'`, what *exactly* should be returned for employee 1, as they have 3 companies associated with them *(3 rows, one for each company)*?

Comment: @JohnWoo, Please read the question (edited).

Comment: @MAK because you are aggregating the `ColumnValue` column. Look at the diffrence between results of `MIN` and `MAX`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a47c7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` employee and use conditional counting in the `HAVING` clause, to get the employee that satisfies the criteria:

```
SELECT ID, EmpName      
FROM EMPDetails 
GROUP BY ID, EmpName
HAVING COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Company' AND 
                     ColumnValue = 'Microsoft' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
       AND 
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Profession' AND 
                ColumnValue = 'Database' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
```

The above query picks employees having `Microsoft` as a `Company` **and** `Database` as a `Profession`.

**Output:**

```
ID  EmpName
------------
1   S
```

You can now use conditional aggregation to pivot the employee rows:

```
SELECT ID, EmpName,
       'Microsoft' AS Company,
       'Database' AS Profession,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'Location' THEN ColumnValue END) AS Location
FROM EMPDetails 
GROUP BY ID, EmpName
HAVING COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Company' AND 
                     ColumnValue = 'Microsoft' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
       AND 
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Profession' AND 
                     ColumnValue = 'Database' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
```

There is no need to perform aggregation for the Company or the Profession value, as the desired value is guaranteed to belong to the employee group.

**Output:**

```
ID  EmpName Company     Profession  Location
-----------------------------------------
1   S       Microsoft   Database    USA
```

To get the second result set, you can simply replace `Database` by `Software`:

```
SELECT ID, EmpName,
       'Microsoft' AS Company,
       'Software' AS Profession,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'Location' THEN ColumnValue END) AS Location
FROM EMPDetails 
GROUP BY ID, EmpName
HAVING COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Company' AND 
                     ColumnValue = 'Microsoft' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
       AND 
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN ColumnName = 'Profession' AND 
                     ColumnValue = 'Software' THEN 1 
             END) > 0
```

**Output:**

```
ID  EmpName Company     Profession  Location
---------------------------------------------
3   R       Microsoft   Software    UK
2   U       Microsoft   Software    UK
```